# rmagick not reading Image correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image-processing, rmagick

I am getting the following error while reading an image through rmagick

```
ERROR: unable to open file `/tmp/magick-XXz9Kxgc': No such file or directory @ constitute.c/ReadImage/569
```

given below is my code

```
   newImg = nil
   img = Magick::Image.read(url)
   img[0].trim!(reset=true)
   size = imageDetails["contraints"].split("x")
   newImg = img[0].resize_to_fill!(size[0].to_i, size[1].to_i,
                                    gravity=CenterGravity)
   newImg.format = "jpeg"
   return newImg.to_blob
```

What might be the issue? Please help.

Comment: Do you have access to the /tmp directory?  This could be a problem creating a temporary file.

Comment: that means that the file isn't existing. upload the file again